# Popup window from asp:Hyperlink with parameter in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, popup

I need open in my `GridView` the `asp:Hyperlink` with parameter to window popup.

Here is a working sample for a popup window with parameter, but I have error.

The error message says:

> Server tag is not correctly formatted.

What's the problem ?

How to do resolve this ?

Can you help me ?

Thank you in advance.

My code below.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="btest">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="btest" Text="btest"
         NavigateUrl='<%#"javascript:_popupWin=window.open('btest.aspx?Sample_ID=" + Eval("Sample_ID") + "',
         '_popupWin','width=300,height=300,resizable=yes,location=yes,scrollbars=yes');_
         popupWin.focus();" %>'>
       </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Replace the `asp:HyperLink` with a normal HTML tag link:

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="btest">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="btest" Text="btest"

        NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("btest.aspx?sID={0}", Eval("Sample_ID"))%>' 
        onclick="javascript:w= window.open(this.href,'Sample_ID',
       'left=20,top=20,width=1500,height=300,toolbar=0,resizable=0');return false;">

       </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```